# How to skip intermediate rows when importing .csv to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I need to import standardized .csv files into a MySQL database, but the files need to be cleaned up before they're turned into tables (remove repeating headers, dates, etc.). Each .csv file is exactly 111 lines and has the same spacing and formatting, so I'd like to build a SQL command that skips the appropriate rows in each file and imports the rest into a table.

Is it possible to do this? I know I can 'IGNORE 1 ROWS' to get past the first row(s), but what about rows further down?

Comment: Do the skip rows have the same format as the other rows? And is each the same? You could just import them all and then delete them afterwards in a single DELETE statement.

Comment: could you provide an example of your "standardized csv"?

Comment: You can do it with 1 line of shell script: line=`head -n 1 standardized.csv`; grep -v "$line"  standardized.csv > new_standardized.csv  and then import the new_standardized,csv : see the Answer

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this in SQL's `LOAD DATA` command. You need to fix up the file before trying to import it. `grep -v` should be useful for this, you just have to determine a pattern that only mathches the lines that should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, in the comment you cant see the ticks

You can do it with 1 line of shell script:

```
line=`head -n 1 standardized.csv`; grep -v "$line"  standardized.csv > new_standardized.csv
```

and then import the new_standardized,csv

Comment: That assumes that the alternate lines are all the same, though, doesn't it? I think?